# Wall-mounted Ethernet switch, how to install?

Tags: walls, receptacle, drill

I have a wall-mounted Ethernet switch that is supposed to be mounted partially inside a wall or panel. There is a mounting bracket included that would fit a standard 60mm can, however the switch does not fit in there, as it uses the rectangular area of the mounting bracket.

[image: Mounting bracket, 60mm can and appropriate drill]

My suspicion is that this is a collision of a product for the US market with German wiring standards. How would I mount such a bracket to a wall properly, leaving a close to rectangular space inside the wall below the opening (the switch doesn't protrude far into the wall, 1cm should be enough)?

Comment: Low voltage wiring doesn't require a box. I suspect that the recessed holes at the sides are intended for mounting. I'd screw it to the wall and cut out the drywall as needed. You could probably mount it to a triple-gang box, too.

Comment: @isherwood, this isn't drywall though, but bricks.

Comment: That just makes the cut more challenging. :)

Comment: If you're saying that you want a surface mount arrangement, that's not clear from your question. Simply use standoffs of some sort to create clearance behind.